# How to apply trim function inside this query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, select-query

Below is simple sql query to select records using in condition.

```
--like this I have 600 usernames
select * from tblUsers where Username in ('abc  ','xyz  ',' pqr  ',' mnop  ' );
```

I know there are `LTrim` & `Rtrim` in sql to remove the leading trailing spaces form left & right respectively.

I want to remove the spaces from left & right in all the usernames that I am supplying to the select query.

**Note:- I want to trim the values that I am passing in the `in` clause**.(*I don't want to pass LTrim & RTrim to each value passed*).

> How to use the `trim` function in the select query?

I am using MS SQL Server 2012